# flatpickr maxDate configuration

Tags: jquery

How to set maxDate in flatpickr?

```
<input type="text" id="date-picker" class="form-control" data-toggle="date" placeholder="Select date">

$("#date-picker").flatpickr("minDate", "2019-7-12");
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [options](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#supplying-dates-for-flatpickr)

```js
$("#date-picker").flatpickr({
  "minDate": "2019-7-12",
  "maxDate": "2019-8-12"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<input type="text" id="date-picker" class="form-control" data-toggle="date" placeholder="Select date">
```

Comment: @RahulDewangan what is your case explain briefly

Comment: I have added all libraries you wrote above but still I'm able to select previous date from 2019-7-12

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking for an answer after reading other solutions... Date must be a date object, not a string!

```
$("#date-picker").flatpickr({
  minDate: "today",
  maxDate: new Date("2019-08-12") 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Aswin Kumar has the right idea, but you might also need to *initialize* the new `flatpickr`. Something like:

```
function InitFlatPickr() {
  $("#date-picker").flatpickr({
    "minDate": "today",
    "maxDate": "2019-8-12"
  });
}
```

And then call your `InitFlatpickr` in either the document ready or something else. The documentation should also be able to help you out.